# Error : Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in PHP 7

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

i hope someone can help me to solve this thing. Just for Information

1. XAMPP 32 bit
2. sqlsrv driver 32 bit
3. odbc 64 bit (i think)
4. my operating system 64 bit

and this is my code to

```
<?php
    $serverName = "REI\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test_db", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) 
    {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

when i am copy sqlsrv 64 bit version into php.ini, i got error undefined sqlsrv, but when i am copy sqlsrv 32 bit version into php.ini, i got error to install odbc 32 bit version. I know that i can't to install 32 bit version because my OS has 64 bit version.

Hope someone can give me a solution or advice to solve this.
Thank you and have a great day

Comment: what do you mean by *'copy sqlsrv into php.ini'* ? is the sqlsrv extension installed and activated ?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ yes when i use sqlsrv 32 bit version, it installed, and i can sqlsrv information on phpinfo() but it request to install odbc 32 bit version. And then when i use sqlsrv 64 bit version, it not installed, and show error that sqlsrv is undefined